# How to filter date column in SASDataView object in VBA (SAS Excel Add in for Excel 2007)

Tags: excel, vba, date, sas

I have a UserForm with a button. I want to apply filter to Date_ID field the sheet in workbook that contains a link to SAS dataset on button click.

Format of Date_ID field in SAS dataset is ddmmyy10.
In Excel sheet that contains a link to SAS dataset it is displayed as "31.10.2015"

Part of UserForm code with declarations:

```
Public excelSASAddIn As SASExcelAddIn 
Public datafeed As SASDataView

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 

    Set excelSASAddIn = Application.COMAddIns.Item("SAS.ExcelAddIn").Object 
    Set datafeed = excelSASAddIn.GetDataView("SASApp_REPORTS_DATAFEED") 

End Sub
```

Button click code:

```
Private Sub createReportButton_Click()
    datafeed.Filter = "Date_ID = 31/10/2015"
    datafeed.Refresh
End Sub
```

So, if I hardcode the date I do not get an error but SASDataView object on sheet is filtered to 0 rows, which clearly should not be the case. Also tried hardcoding 10/31/2015

I've tried using something DatePSerial:

```
Dim dateText As String 

dateText = Format(DateSerial(2015, 10, 31), "dd/MM/yyyy") 
topsFlops.Filter = "Date_ID = " & dateText
```

but this causes an error because of my regional settings. dateText is "31.10.2015" instead of 31/10/2015

I have also tried something like this:

```
topsFlops.Filter = "Date_ID >= 31/10/2015 and Date_ID < 01/11/2015"
```

but this also filters to 0 rows...

I've looked at Help for SASExcel Add-in but there is no example of how to filter date fields, only text fields...

Thanks in advance! Cheers! :)

Comment: Not sure if the code is expecting a SAS date or Excel date. If the code is supposed to be a SAS variable, you would use "31Oct2015"d as the date format.

Comment: I've tried '31Oct2015'd, which caused an error. I will try tomorrow, when I get to work, double quotes instead of single.

Comment: You can also try converting the date to the number of days from 1/1/1960.    31OCT2015 converts to 20392.

Comment: @DomPazz, you were right, double quotes are needed. Its not working if you filter it with single quotes, but with double it works. Write that down as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Reeza had the better answer.  I will let her write the answer and take the credit.

Comment: @Reeza, Please put your comment as answer. Sorry for late reply :)